# Could not able to add biometric dependency in build.gradle file . Facing below error

Tags: android-biometric-prompt

> Could not find method implementation() for arguments [**androidx.biometric:biometric:1.0.1**] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Note : Not using AndroidStudio to compile the apk . Using Make files to compile .

Comment: Does the implementation statement in your build.gradle file look like this: 
implementation "androidx.biometric:biometric:1.0.1" 
(with the quotes)? Btw. consider upgrading, 1.0.1 is rather old.

Comment: i have tried with 1.1.0 which is a stable release but still facing issue with same signature     
i have kept this inside dependency block in gradle file 
implementation "androidx.biometric:biometric:1.1.0"

Comment: Could you show your build.gradle file? Also, which gradle version do you use?